# C# Having two programs reading and writing to the same text file

Tags: c#

Is there a way to have the first program writing to the text file, whilst the program waits until the text file is not being used by another process.

Comment: You will have to expand on that waiting part. The question is unclear now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `FileSystemWatcher` class in the second program, to see when the first program is done. The `FileSystemWatcher` will trigger an event if the file has been created, modified, or deleted.

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: That's unlikely to prevent race conditions with 2 programs randomly writing to a text file - by the time the watcher has fired, the first program might have started a second write.

Comment: I'm not sure whether FileSystemWatcher can tell you that no other processs have a handle to that file. It only can check for creation, deletion and modification, but that's not really sufficient here.

Comment: It's just an idea. Of course he is going to have to handle possible issues when he tries to write on the file.

Comment: @HanletEscaño He has to handle file-locking issues anyway, so your solution doesn't really improve it for him...

Comment: @RB, of course it does, if he has some mechanism that will tell him when he could possibly start writing on the file. Writing an extra program to just dp this is complicating if you asked me. A windows service will just do the same: Watch for changes in the file.

Comment: It doesn't improve it - he will still have to have a separate mechanism for dealing with locked files. With your approach he will have 2 mechanisms for dealing with locked files, which is more programming effort for no meaningful improvement. Also, the FileSystemWatcher is notoriously unreliable, so you would not want to rely on it anyway.

Comment: It is unreliable, in that I do agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to implement a 3rd program which acts as a queue. Your first 2 programs send data to this program, which does the actual writing to the text file.

This 3rd program could be an MSMQ, or a Windows Service, or a set of web-services, or anything - it depends on your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the race condition. You will have to implement try-wait-retry option.

Try to read from file
if it fails then wait for a while and try again

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You place each logical write onto the end of a queue. In another thread you read logical writes from the front of the queue and attempt to write them to the file (open file, write, close file); if an IOException occurs during this then you leave the write on the front of the queue, otherwise you remove it from the front of the queue. If both processes following this pattern then they will be able to interleave writes to the file.